# Can "struct sigaction" be reused after calling sigaction()?

Tags: c, signals

Is it possible to re-use the same `struct sigaction` to set dispositions for many signals? For example, is the following code valid?

```
#include <signal.h>

struct sigaction sa; /* global */

void timeout(int sig) { }
void terminate(int sig) { }

void main(void)
{
  sa.sa_handler = timeout;
  sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
  sa.sa_flags = 0;
  sigaction(SIGALRM, &sa, NULL);

  sa.sa_handler = terminate;
  sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
  sa.sa_flags = 0;
  sigaction(SIGTERM, &sa, NULL);
}
```

Comment: Yes; the kernel makes a copy of the information it needs. You can change the structure without affecting what the kernel knows.  It’s just as well, really; the variable can go out of scope without breaking anything.

Comment: You could check the return value of `sigaction`, 0 indicates success and -1 error (`errno` will be set). This way you can test the behavior of `sigaction` nicely